# How can i add bass to my ringtones on lumia 625?

Tags: lumia, ringtone

I want to know if it is possible for me to add bass to my ringtones or atleast modify the sound so that i can hear the bass. Without bass, my ringtone is just loud noise.

Comment: You can add bass with a 3rd party sound file editor, but most phones can't reproduce very well via their inbuilt speakers.